# date and time oracle error

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle10g

I am trying to show the date and time in oracle where I have altered the date and time formats as:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY MM DD';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS';
insert into train 
  values(18103,'2011/apr/30 21:00:00','2011/apr/31 21:00:00','abl','ndl');
```

But I am getting the error as `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

I have also tried entering the date and time as, `2011/04/30 21:00:00` but still it returns the same error! help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY MM DD';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS';`

these have to be combined.  eg

`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY MM DD HH24:MI:SS'`

also on your insert be sure to `TO_DATE` eg `to_date('2011/apr/31 21:00:00', 'yyyy/mon/dd hh24:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 2):

Your nls_date_format does not match the format of the date string you insert. It should be:

```
SQL>ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY/MON/DD HH24:MI:SS';

session SET altered.

SQL>insert into dat 
    values('2011/apr/30 21:00:00');

1 rows inserted.

SQL>select d from dat;

D                    
----------------------
2011/APR/30 21:00:00
```